# How correct import styles

Tags: javascript, css, sass, vite, shadow-dom

I using vanilla javascript + Vite, why styles doesn't work?

this point I import style of logo component and this is common style.css

```
@import url("./CORE/Logo/style.scss");

*,
body,
html {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

and this is section logo component and how this I import my style from common style.css and implemented

```
import "../../style.css"

export default () =>
    `
    <main>
        <section>
            <figcaption class="logo">
                <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
            </figcaption>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p class="name">Test</p>
        </section>
   </main>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import CSS using import assertions, see https://web.dev/articles/css-module-scripts.

```
import sheet from "../../style.css" with {type: "css"};
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
```

Comment: this is get me error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ShadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets setter: Element of value being assigned is not an object.
and I ask chatGPT )) and he get me this solution and this is worked good.
`
const shadowRoot = document.getElementById('your-shadow-root-id').attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
const styleSheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
styleSheet.replaceSync('your css content here');
shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [styleSheet];`

Comment: Here's a working example https://plnkr.co/plunk/Jf9h7HywAtXdxQt0

Answer (score 0):

```
const shadowRoot = document.getElementById('your-shadow-root-id').attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
const styleSheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
await styleSheet.replace('your css content here');
shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [styleSheet];
```

[CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet)